# Trouble Accessing XML after using simplexml

Tags: php, xml

Before someone points out that there are a ton of similar questions like this, please keep in mind I have tried and exhausted all methods I could find here on stacked.

I'm having trouble using simplexml to pull out the data I want from a response that is structured like this.

```
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:body>
  <authenticateresponse xmlns="http://somesite.co.nz">
    <authenticateresult>
      <username>Username</username>
      <token>XXXXXXXXX</token>
      <reference>
        <message>Access Denied</message>
      </reference>
    </authenticateresult>
  </authenticateresponse>
</soap:body>
```

In this case I'd like to know how to pull out the token and username.

Comment: Very likely, the *default namespace* (`xmlns="http://somesite.co.nz"`) causes you the problem. Read : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2386706/2998271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace declared at `authenticateresponse` element :

```
xmlns="http://somesite.co.nz"
```

Notice that the element where default namespace is declared along with the descendant elements without prefix are in the same namespace. To access element in default namespace, you need to map a prefix to the namespace URI and use the prefix in the XPath, for example :

```
$raw = <<<XML
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:body>
  <authenticateresponse xmlns="http://somesite.co.nz">
    <authenticateresult>
      <username>Username</username>
      <token>XXXXXXXXX</token>
      <reference>
        <message>Access Denied</message>
      </reference>
    </authenticateresult>
  </authenticateresponse>
</soap:body>
</soap:envelope>
XML;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($raw);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'http://somesite.co.nz');
$username = $xml->xpath('//d:username');
echo $username[0];
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/559861)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
Username
```

A few former related questions :

- [Parsing XML with PHP's simpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386490/parsing-xml-with-phps-simplexml)
- [XPath in SimpleXML for default namespaces without needing prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143846/xpath-in-simplexml-for-default-namespaces-without-needing-prefixes)

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm just going over some of those other questions. For some bizzare reason even when I rewrite my code exactly as you have done it is still failing, I'm getting an undefined offset on username.

Comment: Could you post short demo, probably in eval.in, that reproduces the problem? Otherwise I have no idea...

Comment: Your solution works when I write it in statically, error has to be in the response data somewhere, I only posted a fraction of it here. Thanks for the help much appreciated. @har07